# Invalid or unexpected token using post method to firebase database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to insert a static array to my firebase db. This is what my current db looks like.
[image]

What I wanted to create is something like this.
[image]

```
router.post('/:uuid', function (req, res) {
    var ref = database.ref('watchers/' + req.params.uuid);
    var body = _.pick(_.assign(addwatcher, req.body), _.keys(addwatcher)); 

    body['createdAt'] = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

    body['totalRating'] = {1star:0,2star:0,3star:0,4star:0,5star:0,total:0};

    ref.set(body);

    res.send('Sucessfully authenticated!');

});
```

I'm using this script to save my auth id instead of pushId, but when I tried to but my problem when I tried to create an array it sends error on my console..

```
body['totalRating'] = {1star:0,2star:0,3star:0,4star:0,5star:0,total:0};
                       ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

I just wanted to know on how to insert array data on .post method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use number as first character in naming a variable in javascript. Try it in your developer's console you'll get this.

[image]

**Update**

If you really want to achieve that you can do this `{'1star': 0}`. Just wrap the var name between single quotation marks (or double quotation marks).

[image]

Comment: any idea on how to achive the sample result on the 2nd image?.

Comment: Just change the variable names inside your array to `star1`, `star2` can you try that first?

Comment: i tried it and is works.. im just hoping if it is possible to insert a number as 1st character on my variable..

Comment: No problem at all. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

### Naming Conventions

**All names start with a letter.**

Always use the same naming convention for all your code. For example:

Variable and function names written as **camelCase**

Global variables written in **UPPERCASE** (We don't, but it's quite common)

Constants (like PI) written in **UPPERCASE**

Should you use **hyp-hens**, **camelCase**, or **under_scores** in variable names?

This is a question programmers often discuss. The answer depends on who you ask:

#### Hyphens in HTML and CSS:

HTML5 attributes can start with data- (data-quantity, data-price).

CSS uses hyphens in property-names (font-size).

Hyphens can be mistaken as subtraction attempts. Hyphens are not allowed in JavaScript names.

#### Underscores:

Many programmers prefer to use underscores (date_of_birth), especially in SQL databases.

Underscores are often used in PHP documentation.

#### PascalCase:

PascalCase is often preferred by C programmers.

#### camelCase:

camelCase is used by JavaScript itself, by jQuery, and other JavaScript libraries.

Do not start names with a $ sign. It will put you in conflict with many JavaScript library names.

[Naming Conventions For Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)